# Android: disable onClickListener within its own onClick?

Tags: android, onclicklistener

In Android (targeting APIs 14-16) I have an `onClickListener` set for a `TextView` as below:

```
theView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // actions
    }
});
```

One of the consequences of clicking should be to disable further clicks. I've tried including `v.setOnClickListener(null);` among the "actions", but it doesn't have the required effect. What should I be doing for this?

---

**Edit**: @Raghav Sood suggests disabling the TextView. In this case, I have a large grid of TextViews of which only one was clicked; I want to disable all of them. I suppose I must disable all with a loop; is that correct? Or is there a single command that can disable the whole layout in which they reside?

Answer (score 8):

Don't disable the onClickListener, disable the TextView:

```
TextView.setEnabled(false);
```

Comment: This didn't work for me when setting the on click listener with ButterKnife. I used `setClickable()`.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is old but still...

```
theView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
     @Override
     public void onClick(View v) {
         v.setClickable(false);
                 v.setClickable(false);
                // actions
         }
});
```